# What is best way to determine if the user is actually using Safari?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

What is best way to determine if the user is actually using Safari?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to detect Safari specifically?

Comment: In most cases you do not want to detect the browser, just browser capabilities. What are you doing that requires that you send Safari something just because it's Safari?

Comment: What are you guys concerning about? =)

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved successfully? Do you still need help with this?

Answer (score 4):

You might want to read http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html and then http://www.quirksmode.org/js/support.html and understand that the best you can do is probe what the user tells you is the browser they are using (this would be the User_Agent). You can never say with 100% certainty that they are using a given browser, because you have to rely on what is transmitted from the browser and it can be overriden at many points.

However, the quirksmode.org solution is usually the best way to deal with a single check across all engines and browsers.

Are you using a particular javascript framework that could allow you to more accurately determine what they're using? What serverside language are you using? (and as somebody else asked, why Safari only?)

Comment: Too many questions that have nothing to do with my question. It's just your curiosity... lol!

Comment: @cover ~ Be that as it may, they are still valid questions. Please accept an answer or close the question. Be a good community member.

Answer (score 1):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent

Answer (score 1):

Others have already noted that browser sniffing is not ideal, but there are cases where a bug only happens in a browser and it can be hard to detect. In that case, you can do browser sniffing and hope the user agent string is valid. Here's what Ext-JS does.

```
var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var isChrome = /\bchrome\b/.test(ua);
var isSafari = !isChrome && /safari/.test(ua);
```

Line 62 of view-source:http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/source/Ext.html has all of Ext's browser detection in an easy to read format.

This is brittle and will probably not work as new versions and browsers come out.

Tell us why you're testing for safari, so we can make sure there isn't a better way to achieve what you want.

Comment: This is my alternate preferred method. aka this is what I would prefer to rely on.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("safari") != -1 && navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("chrome") == -1){
    // you code here
}
```